# is it possible to implement Turn by Turn navigation sdk from mapbox on Android Google Maps?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

i have create a tracking project using maps from Google on android kotlin, and i want to create more that user can go to somewhere with navigation (so  there's two point, a current location point and destination point). i want to implement turn by turn navigation sdk from mapbox? is it possible to do that? have you build it before?

Answer (score 0):

ya turn by turn navigation is tricky.Map box should make it easier though u just have to implement there sdk in your project and they also have docs on how to use the Map box sdk. only downfall is you have to pay for it.

i would advise if you are creating a personal project try creating a location listener and update current position of the device on a google maps intent. you can then just create your own navigation app  ( its abit of a longer way around it but you would have more control over the navigation and plus its free)

Comment: i always find the example that using maps from mapbox not maps from google. mapbox only can be run at sdk above 27?

Comment: Mapbox turn by turn navigation is free unto a point. Depends on how much 'use' your app will get. https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the Navigator

```
        NavigationApi.getNavigator(requireActivity(), object : NavigationApi.NavigatorListener {
    /**
     * Sets up the navigation UI when the navigator is ready for use.
     */
    override fun onNavigatorReady(navigator: Navigator) {
         
        
    }

    /**
     * Handles errors from the Navigation SDK.
     * @param errorCode The error code returned by the navigator.
     */
    override fun onError(@NavigationApi.ErrorCode errorCode: Int) {
     }
})
```

Register for Navigation Updates

```
       val success = navigator?.registerServiceForNavUpdates(
        requireContext().packageName,
        NavInfoReceivingService::class.java.name,
        Int.MAX_VALUE
    ) // Send all remaining steps.
    if (success == true) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully registered service for nav updates")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to register service for nav updates")
    }
```

Unregister for Navigation Updates

```
  val success = navigator?.unregisterServiceForNavUpdates()
    if (success == true) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unregistered service for nav updates")
    } else {
        // This may happen if no service had been registered.
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to unregister service for nav updates")
    }
```

Create Service class to listen for Turn by turn updates

```
class NavInfoReceivingService : Service() {
/** The messenger used by the service to receive nav step updates. */
private var incomingMessenger: Messenger? = null

/** Used to read incoming messages. */
private var turnByTurnManager: TurnByTurnManager? = null

override fun onCreate() {
    turnByTurnManager = TurnByTurnManager.createInstance()
    val thread = HandlerThread(TAG, Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    thread.start()
    incomingMessenger = Messenger(IncomingNavStepHandler(thread.looper))
}

private inner class IncomingNavStepHandler(looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        if (TurnByTurnManager.MSG_NAV_INFO == msg.what) {
            // Read the nav info from the message data,
            // and post the value (if it exists) to LiveData to be displayed in the nav info header.
            turnByTurnManager?.readNavInfoFromBundle(msg.data).let { navInfo ->
                navInfoMutableLiveData.postValue(navInfo)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return incomingMessenger?.binder
}

override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent): Boolean {
    navInfoMutableLiveData.postValue(null)
    return super.onUnbind(intent)
}


companion object {
    private const val TAG = "NavInfoReceivingService"
    private val navInfoMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<NavInfo?>()
    val navInfoLiveData: LiveData<NavInfo?>
        get() = navInfoMutableLiveData
}
```

}

Register the service in Manifest

```
  <service
        android:name="com.bosch.re.service.NavInfoReceivingService"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Register for Navinfo live data

```
NavInfoReceivingService.navInfoLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, navInfoObserver)
 private val navInfoObserver = Observer { navInfo: NavInfo? ->
    navInfo?.let { showNavInfo(it) }
}
```

Now you can able to get the Turn by turn information

[NavInfo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/mapsplatform/turnbyturn/model/NavInfo)

Dont forget to startGuidance

```
navigator?.startGuidance()
```